# Inline кнопки не отвечают на нажатия

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Вот код

```
@dp.message_handler(state=Form.buy_or_more)
async def process_inline(message: types.Message):

    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    buy_button = InlineKeyboardButton('Купить билет', callback_data='buy')
    more_button = InlineKeyboardButton('Подробнее о встрече 10 декабря', callback_data='more')
    keyboard.add(buy_button)
    keyboard.add(more_button)

    await message.answer("Выберите действие:", reply_markup=keyboard)

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'buy')
async def process_callback_buy(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)

    buy_ticket_text = "Вы можете купить билет по ссылке: [Ссылка на покупку билета]"
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, buy_ticket_text)
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, "Если вы купили, отправьте скриншот")

    await Form.screen.set()

@dp.message_handler(content_types=['photo'], state=Form.screen)
async def process_screenshot(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    # Process the screenshot
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Спасибо. Мне нужно немного времени, чтобы обработать запрос. "
                                                  "Электронный билет придет на почту в ближайшее время.")

    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Напишите от 1 до 3х вопросов, которые интересуют вас по теме WWTalks. "
                                                  "Самые интересные мы обсудим на нашей встрече.")
    await Form.next()

@dp.message_handler(state=Form.questions)
async def process_questions(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    # Process the questions
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Спасибо за участие в формировании актуальных вопросов для ####. "
                                                 "Ждем вас на нашей встрече!\n\nКоманда ######")
    await Form.buy_or_more.set()


@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'more')
async def process_callback_buy(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)

    details_text = "Тема: 'Карьера'\n" 
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, details_text)
```

Почему не работают inline кнопки?
Я думаю это как-то связано с состояниями.

У меня есть код который работает. В нем нету состояния у inline кнопок

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    buy_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Купить билет', callback_data='buy')
    more_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Подробнее о встрече 10 декабря', callback_data='more')
    keyboard.add(buy_button, more_button)

    await message.answer("Выберите действие:", reply_markup=keyboard)


@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'buy')
async def process_callback_buy(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    buy_ticket_text = "Вы можете купить билет по ссылке: [Ссылка на покупку билета]"
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, buy_ticket_text)
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, "Если вы купили, отправьте скриншот")
    await Form.screen.set()

@dp.message_handler(content_types=['photo'], state=Form.screen)
async def process_screenshot(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):

    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Спасибо. Мне нужно немного времени, чтобы обработать запрос. "
                                                  "Электронный билет придет на почту в ближайшее время.")

    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Напишите от 1 до 3х вопросов, которые интересуют вас по теме WWTalks. "
                                                  "Самые интересные мы обсудим на нашей встрече.")
    await Form.questions.set()

@dp.message_handler(state=Form.questions)
async def process_questions(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):

    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Спасибо за участие в формировании актуальных вопросов для #####. "
                                                 "Ждем вас на нашей встрече!\n\nКоманда #####")
    await state.finish()

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'more')
async def process_callback_buy(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)

    details_text = "Тема: 'Карьера'\n" 
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, details_text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В предыдущем вашем вопросе я подсказал по поводу состояний, если брать тот кусок кода с клавиатурой

```
@dp.message_handler(state=Form.email)
async def process_phone(message: types.Message):
    email = message.text
    if email.startswith("@"):
        keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        buy_button = InlineKeyboardButton('Купить билет', callback_data='buy')
        more_button = InlineKeyboardButton('Подробнее о встрече 10 декабря', callback_data='more')
        keyboard.add(buy_button)
        keyboard.add(more_button)
        await message.answer("Выберите действие:", reply_markup=keyboard)
        # await Form.buy_or_more.set()  <- тут убираем явное назначение состояния
    else:
        await message.answer("Напиши, пожалуйста, email (важно, т.к. электронный адрес должен совпадать с тем, что ты укажешь при оплате")
```

убираем в нем явное назначение следующего состояния. И вместо этого для обработчиков кнопок указывайте `state='*'` вот так

> для кнопки 'Купить билет'

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='buy', state='*')
async def process_callback_buy(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(call.id)
    buy_ticket_text = "Вы можете купить билет по ссылке: [Ссылка на покупку билета]"  # Замените ссылкой на покупку билета
    await bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, buy_ticket_text)
    await bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, "Если вы купили, отправьте скриншот")
    await Form.screen.set() # <- регистрируем следующее состояние

@dp.message_handler(content_types=['photo'], state=Form.screen)
async def process_screenshot(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    # Process the screenshot
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Спасибо. Мне нужно немного времени, чтобы обработать запрос. "
                                                 "Электронный билет придет на почту в ближайшее время.")

    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Напишите от 1 до 3х вопросов, которые интересуют вас по теме WWTalks. "
                                                 "Самые интересные мы обсудим на нашей встрече.")
    await Form.next()
```

> для кнопки 'Подробнее о встрече 10 декабря'

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='more', state='*')
async def process_callback_buy(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)

    details_text = "Тема: 'Карьера'\n"
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, details_text)
```

в таком случае хэндлеры должны отлавливать нажатия кнопок, когда запущено какое нибудь состояние

Comment: а на каких гайдах ты учился? Каких ботов будет полезно сделать чтобы продвинуться в развитии?

Comment: добавил к buy - Form.screen.set() и он не переходит на это состояние. Отправляю скриншот и ничего

Comment: дописал код, бот должен отлавливать картинки, отправленные как медиа-файл, т.е. с сжатием. Если вы отправляете скриншот как файл, то  его нужно отлавливать хэндлером с `content_types=['document']`. Ну и как я ранее писал, то могу предположить, что следующая проблема, с которой вы столкнетесь - это где взять данные, которые вводил пользователь